# Why is fetchAll() returning an empty array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Ultimately, my goal is to return the integer locationID. But the Array returned from SQL statement is empty. the SQL statement returns only one row, I checked in phpMyAdmin. I also made sure my parameters are being properly input. Why is the array empty? I'm trying to return the data from the one relevant row in my database, I figured it would be $result[0] or $result['cityID'] (aka the name of the column pf the row data I'm trying to return) but neither work, I'm assuming because the array is empty, but I can't figure out why its empty...something I'm missing? thanks in advance.

```
public function getLocationID($frmtCity, $frmtState){
    $sql = 'SELECT cityID FROM city WHERE city.name = :name AND city.stateID = :state';

    $queryStmt = $this -> conn -> prepare($sql);

    if($queryStmt -> execute(array(':name'=>$frmtCity, ':state'=>$frmtState)) ){

        $result = $queryStmt -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        print_r($result);
    }
}
```

Comment: @giollianosulit Thanks. I didn't read the post correctly but I think he needs to use `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`  instead of `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

Comment: If you're getting an empty result, it means that there are no rows that match the criteria in `WHERE`.

Answer (score -2):

You should try this simple and easy:

```
public function getLocationID(){
$sql = 'SELECT cityID FROM city WHERE city.name = :name AND city.stateID = :state';

$queryStmt = $this -> conn -> query($sql);

if($queryStmt->rowCount() > 0) ){

    $result = $queryStmt -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

}else{
    $result = 0;
} 
return $result;
}
```

Comment: I use prepared statements and execute() for sql injection prevention. your condition proves that I'm not returning rows, but I already knew I'm not getting anything back, even though when I run the SQL statement in phpMyAdmin I get one row back

Comment: my friend prepare statement for inserting and query is fetching,updating and deleting you need to more study on PDO.

Comment: This will never work. You can't use parameters like `:name` unless you use a prepared query.